# Jest Code coverage for parameter function send from mock

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

We sending the callback function to a function and calls the function inside it, and i need to cover the test case.
How to cover these function inside button onclick in jest unit testing.

code:

```
export const Action = (alertfn, value) => {
  if (value > 10) {
    alertfn({
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "yes",
          onclick: () => {
            // yesonlickfn;
          },
        },
        {
          text: "no",
          onclick: () => {
            // noonlickfn;
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  }
};
```

myTestcase for other this

```
test('Action', () => {
    const mockfn = jest.fn();
    Action(mockfn, 5);
    expect(mockfn).toHaveBeenValledWith({
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "yes",
                onclick: jest.fn() 
            },
            {
                text: "no",
                onclick: jest.fn() 
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

myTestcase to cover this, but not working.

```
test('Action', () => {
    const mockfn = jest.fn(x => x);
    Action(mockfn, 5);
    expect(mockfn).toHaveBeenValledWith({
        buttons: [
            {text: "yes",onclick: jest.fn() },
            {text: "no",onclick: jest.fn() }
        ]
    });
    const s = mockfn({
        buttons: [
            {text: "yes",onclick: jest.fn()},
            {text: "no",onclick: jest.fn()}
        ]
    });
    s.buttons[0].onclick.sample()
});
```

also tried with
`jest.spyOn(s.buttons[0].onclick)`